# Linking library with G++

Tags: hyperlink, g++

Sorry for asking this newbie question but I can't get off this s***t...

In the same directory I have 4 files : `ctacs.ini`; `ct_api.h`; `libctacs.a` and `main.cpp`.
My cpp file contains   `#include "ct_api.h"` and when I try to compile with :

`g++ -lctacs main.cpp -o main`

I got undefined references to the functions which are defined in my library -__-

Could you please tell what did I wrong ? I search on the internet but the option `-lctacs` seems to be the right way to proceed...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some compilers and linkers resolve references to functions by searching the object files/sources files/libraries left-to-right on the command line. This means that files that call externally-defined functions should appear *before* the object files/libraries/source files that contain their definitions.

You happen to have a linker that does indeed depend on this ordering. You need to put the library *after* `main.cpp` so that the function definitions can be found:

```
g++ main.cpp -lctacs -o main
```